# Is it possible to switch wifi networks in Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

While executing my test suite I have to switch between different wifi networks available in Android Device.
In the middle of the execution I have to change my wifi connection from Wifi_Network_1 to Wifi_Network_2 provided ssid name and password of wifi network is known. How can it be done?
I am using:

```
Appium server -->1.8.1
java-client --> 6.1.0
selenium-java --> 3.13.0
```

Since NetworkConnectionSetting  has been deprciated, I am not able to find alternate for it. 
I can toggle wifi on/off using

```
driver.toggleWifi();
```

But it is not suitable for my case as i need to toggle between different wifi network available using SSID name and its password.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'am using this method due Appium deprecated their switch for wifi, and I've created my own override via console via commands from adb. It is working for me so give it a try:

```
public synchronized boolean wifiSetup(String udid, boolean flg) {
    synchronized (this) {
        String flgEnabled = (flg) ? "enable" : "disable";


        List<String> output = Console.runProcess(false, "adb -s " + udid + " shell am broadcast -a io.appium.settings.wifi --es setstatus " + flgEnabled);
        for (String line : output) {
            System.err.println(line);
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Broadcast completed: result=-1"))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

usage to switch **off**:

```
wifiSetup("xxxUDIDfromAndroid", false);
```

usage to switch **on**:

```
wifiSetup("xxxUDIDfromAndroid", true);
```

And here is part for calling console:

```
public class Console {
    private static final String[] WIN_RUNTIME = { "cmd.exe", "/C" };
    private static final String[] OS_LINUX_RUNTIME = { "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" };

    private Console() {

    }

    private static <T> T[] concat(T[] first, T[] second) {
        T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "hiding"})
    private static <String> String[] concatStr(String[] first, String[] second) {
        String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }



    public static List<String> runProcess(boolean isWin, String... command) {           
        String[] allCommand = null;
        try {
            if (isWin) {
                allCommand = concat(WIN_RUNTIME, command);
            } else {
                allCommand = concat(OS_LINUX_RUNTIME, command);
            }
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(allCommand);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String _temp = null;
            List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((_temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
//              system.out.println("temp line: " + _temp);
                line.add(_temp);
            }
//          system.out.println("result after command: " + line);
            return line;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

}

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am able to toggle wifi on/off using driver.toggleWifi(). But what i need is to toggle between different wifi network available using wifi's ssid name and password.